# No Content in Home Page

Tags: installation

I downloaded a Store from live Server and trying to install it in my local machine. But no Content is loading in Home Page.

[image]

Output of **debug.log** file is like below
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["LAYOUT_GENERAL_CACHE_TAG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BLOCK_HTML"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["COLLECTION_DATA"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["REFLECTION"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["DB_DDL"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["COMPILED_CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["CUSTOMER_NOTIFICATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION_API_CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["GOOGLE_PRODUCT"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["WEBSERVICE"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["TRANSLATE"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["VERTEX"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:27] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_SYSTEM_CONFIG"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:27] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2021-12-11 01:36:28] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http://127.0.0.1/ashrafvai/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_SYSTEM_CONFIG"}} []
I ran below commands.
**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

**php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

**php bin/magento cache:clean**

**php bin/magento cache:flush**

But I am not getting Content of Home Page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB -f
```

Try this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have not run deployed that why this error is shown

so can you please one time run the below command after your side will work

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

Thanks